# how are deleted files stored in recycle bin

Tags: recycle-bin

since we are able to recover them later I am guessing some information about the files will he stored but having entire files stored untill recycle bin is emptied seems a brute effort.

so what information of deleted files are stored and does it requires main memory?

suppose in my htc smartphone with 8gb capacity  I have deleted some 5gb data and not emptied the recycle bin next I use store some new data so will I have all the space available and if i pack my phone with about 8gb data and later wish to recover the previously deleted 5gb data, given I make space for it by deleting currently stored data.

Comment: I believe Recycle Bin do use up your free space and it's just a special directory which can't execute nor do anything except for recovering. And it clears up free spaces for you after you 'empty' your recycle bin then it will be mark as 'available space to write data'

Comment: If I'm not wrong, recycle bin is merely used like a blueprint of redundant files and for you to decide later when to permanent free up when you really don't need the file and need space, then you empty it for free space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you a delete a file, it is not erased/deleted permenently from the drive unless we clean by emptying the recycle bin**

Operating Systems keep track of where files are on a hard drive using “pointers.” Each and every file/folder on the hard disk has a pointer that specifies where the file’s data begins and ends.So when we delete a file, Operating System removes the pointer and marks the sectors containing the file’s data as available in other words free memory . From the file system’s point of view, the file is no longer present on your hard drive.

So untill we write new data to the sectors ,the deleted data will still remain in that sector.

A file recovery program can scan a hard drive for these deleted files and restore them.IF a portion of the entire file has been overwritten, then the file cannot be recovered completely.

Comment: so basically recycle bin is a system to store the files who you man want restored in future but have deleted for now and if u otherwise use that space , those files in recycle bin cant be restored. Thnx